# Est-ce que "spontané" est le meilleur mot dans ce contexte ?

Tags: vocabulaire, demande-de-mot

Je veux trouver un adjectif pour cette situation, dans un contexte informatique:

> Un agent X est celui qui décide au fur et à mesure de l'arrivée des données.

Est-ce que je peux dire que l'agent X est spontané ? ou y a t-il un autre adjectif?

Comment: C'est l'agent X que tu cherches à qualifier ou son décisionnel *on the fly* ?

Comment: Oui, c'est exactement ça.

Comment: Il manque des éléments de contexte importants pour les lecteurs non spécialisés; s'agit-il d'un contexte relatif à l'informatique?

Comment: Oui c'est relatif à l'informatique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Je n'emploierais pas "spontané" dans ce contexte, car ce qui est spontané est direct, non réfléchi (du moins pas consciemment, ça peut être instinctif) et, surtout, ne se répète pas.

Si l'idée est que chaque nouvelle donnée remplace la précédente, on pourrait utiliser "à la volée" ("on the fly" en anglais, pour un calcul qui reste en mémoire vive) ou "en temps réel" (near-real time, pour un résultat écrit sur le disque toute de suite après la mise à jour des données d'entrée), mais je ne vois pas d'adjectif vraiment approprié, sauf peut-être **instantané** si on veut insister sur la rapidité.

Si l'idée est que chaque nouvelle donnée renforce/modifie la décision, alors on pourrait utiliser **incrémental** (petits changements progressifs à chaque étape) ou **adaptatif** (remise en question en fonction des nouvelles informations).

Answer (score 3):

"au fur et à mesure" décrit d'habitude un processus bien pensé et souvent pas du tout d'une longue durée. Alors, dans ce contexte je ne trouverai pas « spontané » du tout approprié  comme adjectif. Il serait possible, peut être, de décrire l'agent X comme "l'agent en charge".